# showing woocommerce products while cart empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show woo commerce products while cart is empty in same page, for users(login/not logged in). Currently it shows button for **Return to shop** and a message showing "Your Cart is Empty".

Is there any plugin available for the same or how it can be done with code?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What kind of products are you trying to show? Like related to what they had in their cart? Or just random products you're selling?

Comment: Hi, @Ishio there are multiple type of products like book and other language kit. But I want to show random products in cart empty page. I guess we can filter that out later once we can show products over there

Comment: Do you know how to develop for WordPress or are you merely looking for a plugin?

Comment: I'm a newbie to wordpress I wish if there's a plugin available for the same.

Comment: With a plugin, I am not entirely sure. I wasn't able to find any. However it is very easily doable with code experience.

Comment: I wrote this for me, you will need to look stuff up to understand it but it would go in your functions.php file (of  child theme) or a functions plugin or you can use the plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)  https://gist.github.com/carasmo/5fc3efeb283517fb5b39069ade8fbdca -- do not copy the opening php tag.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

I generated a shortcode for recent products from woo commerce plugin and added this code `<?php  echo do_shortcode('[recent_products per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="desc"]'); ?>` to `cart-empty.php` file of woocommerce plugin.